# Defining a quadratic formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Whenever X is doubled, Y is halved for these values. How to write this as a mathematical formula/expression?

```
+----+------+
| Y  |  X   |
+----+------+
| 32 |  100 |
| 16 |  200 |
|  8 |  400 |
|  4 |  800 |
|  2 | 1600 |
+----+------+
```

Comment: **Hint:** What is $x\times y$ equal to in each case in your table?

Comment: It's always 3200

Comment: So... $xy=3200$, or if you insist on having it in the form $y=f(x)$, then divide both sides by $x$ to get $y=\dots$.  As an aside, we say that $x$ and $y$ in this case are [inversely proportional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)#Inverse_proportionality).

Comment: Without the tabulated values, you may write $$y \propto \frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: @NgChungTak How do you mean that Y is proportionate with the inverse of X?

Comment: @Michael That's the notation for inverse proportion which means $xy=k$ as $$\frac{y}{\frac{1}{x}}=k$$ See [**this**](http://images.slideplayer.com/1/222103/slides/slide_4.jpg).  For example, Coulomb's Law of charge or Newton's Law of gravity, we write $$F\propto \frac{1}{r^2}$$ in which force is inversely proportional to distance squared that we call them inverse square laws.

Answer (score 1):

You should note that $x\times y=3200$ in your table. Hope that solved your prob?